# Make a translation for PO files

Tags: php, localization, translation, multilingual, gettext

We are working on web application in PHP and use gettext to handle strings for translation. Here is my question what we are struggling right now.

If we use kind of words/id for a string for example "menu-feature" and we would like to display it in English as "Our main Features" we can do it of course and for example first English translation will be made by a person with access to application. So than we will have "EN" po file ready. 
But if we would like to send it to other translator for example Norwegian so this person will see again only our "IDs". How he/she can find what we had in mind exactly with that ID ??

Do we have bad way of thinking about using PO files? Is a some good way to make it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Common practice is to use the whole actual string in the default language as the msgid, for exactly the reason you've lined out: translators would have a much harder time figuring out the meaning behind each of your placeholders.

That said, you can add comments to each of the ids as a hint for translators. I think those lines start with a # in the .po file. They should also show up in Poedit, Virtaal or whatever they're using.

Comment: yeah we were thinking it that way as well but if we would like to change a text on english site that we have to change ID of a string what can mess up all other translations.

Comment: It depends. If you just need to change the wording slightly, you'd just have to create an actual english .po file instead of letting it fall back to the msgid. If you change the meaning, you would have to change all the translations anyway.

Comment: good point. 
We are thinking about other solution but we affraid that it is a little to "complicated". Make an English file, after that use english translation as an ID for translator (Id->EN-id) to other languges, after translation make a match EN-Id->Id->other-translation. this kind of script would not be hard to make and it will keep actually used ID in the code and give better overview for translators.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used poedit in a while, but why don't you just copy the English file, call it Norwegian, import it in poedit and start editing?

Comment: becasue we would like to use pasolo where you can use autotranslations tools, fuzzy translation etc, and as I know it take as source "source string" not translated.